# Using visual studio 2015 with cmake

Tags: visual-studio-2015, cmake, linker-errors

I have a c++ library(retdec-cpp), which I built and installed using Cmake 3.10.0

I want to use this library in a visual studio 2015 project(this specific version is needed).  I understand that there is a need to build the debug and release seperately, so I followed [this guide](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp_questions/comments/63ccx3/cmake_and_debug_vs_release_builds/).

Now I want to use this c++ library in my Visual Studio project using Cmake, but I'm having trouble with writing CmakeLists.txt

This it how it looks now:

```
project(prog CXX)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)

find_package(Threads)


set(RETDEC_SRC_DIR "C:/Users/kkkkk/Desktop/retdec-cpp")
set(RETDEC_BUILD_DIR "C:/Users/kkkkk/Desktop/retdec-cpp/build")

#added :
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin")
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib")
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib")
#

include_directories(SYSTEM "${RETDEC_SRC_DIR}/include")
link_directories(
    "${RETDEC_BUILD_DIR}/debug/src/retdec"
    "${RETDEC_BUILD_DIR}/debug/third_party/src/cpp-netlib-build/libs/network/src"
    "${RETDEC_BUILD_DIR}/debug/src/json-cpp-build/src/lib_json"
    "${RETDEC_BUILD_DIR}/release/src/retdec"
    "${RETDEC_BUILD_DIR}/release/third_party/src/cpp-netlib-build/libs/network/src"
    "${RETDEC_BUILD_DIR}/release/src/json-cpp-build/src/lib_json"

)


add_executable(prog prog.cpp)
target_link_libraries(
retdec
    boost_filesystem
    boost_system
    boost_thread
    boost_chrono
    boost_date_time
    boost_atomic
    ssl
    crypto
    cppnetlib-uri
    cppnetlib-client-connections
    jsoncpp
    ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT}

)
```

When I build it in visual studio, it keeps on displaying this error:
     **LNK1104:cannot open file retdec.lib**

There is obviously something wrong in my CMakeLists.

How can include this library in my Visual Studio 2015 project using Cmake?

Comment: Is `retdec.lib` in one of your link directories? I would not expect that to be the case. They look like source folders instead.

Comment: you need to call target_link_libraries for an existing target, i.e. you should call it with `prog` as first argument.

Comment: If that library exists in the folder perhaps you are mixing 32 and 64 bit.

Comment: I do have prog as a first argument,for some reason in got cut out.

Comment: the library does not exist in the folder

Comment: Then you need to correct the paths you are using in link_directories().

Comment: The issue is that i cannit find retdec.lib anywhere

Comment: I got these paths from the library writer,excluding the debug/release paths.

Comment: If the binary does not exist you must have not built the library or the build failed when you built it. You need to fix that problem first. Probably ask a different question since building this dependent library does not seem to have anything to do with this question.

Comment: I built this library in cmake,the output was :build succedded.

Comment: the only error was that it couldnt find the the header file: pthread.h but i read in some forum that in windows this should be ignored

Comment: Then you need to find the location of the libraries that the dependent library produced. You said earlier that there was no `retdec.lib` file. Maybe windows is causing the problem by hiding known extensions.

Comment: ***the only error was that it couldnt find the the header file: pthread.h but i read in some forum that in windows this should be ignored*** That could very well cause your library to not be produced.

Comment: Thank you for your help . I will investigate the reason why pthread.h is not found  in depth

Comment: Maybe there is an option in CMake to build the `retdec` library without pthreads. Some projects will have that. Otherwise there is a way to install a pthreads library in windows.

Comment: Do you know where to place pthread.h so that cmake could find it? I have tried all the soultions offered by stackoverflow with no success.

Comment: https://sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/#download

Comment: I downloaded this.My question is where to place the downloaded files on windows system so that cmake should find pthread.h?

Comment: Just to clearify: The issue was not the pthread.h library.Pthread is for linux and is not needed in this case on windows

Answer (score 0):

The problem from the error:

> LNK1104:cannot open file retdec.lib

Results from the fact that all of the directories you specified in the `link_directories()` call, doesn't seem to include `retdec.lib` which you're attempting to link to inside of the the `target_link_libraries()` function.

The solution is simple:

- Find the location of retdec.lib, and place it in one of the folders you've already linked (I spot an item in your link_directories call valued: `"${RETDEC_BUILD_DIR}/release/src/retdec"` was this intended? Judging by the name, it seems like it's directory with src files, not libs. Where you looking for something like `"${RETDEC_BUILD_DIR}/release/lib"` instead?).
- Or, you can find the location of retdec.lib, and then add that directory as an addition in your `link_directories()` list.